# How to invert background pixel's color

Tags: opengl, java, shaders, glsl, jmonkeyengine

I'm writing a game and map editor using Java and jMonkeyEngine. In the map editor, I've got a brush done by wireframed sphere. My problem is: I want to make it visible everywhere, so I want to invert color of the pixel "behind" this brush. I wanted to do it with fragment shader (GLSL), but I don't know how to get color of this pixel.

Comment: Does jMonkeyEngine support post-process effects? You'll probably have to go this way.

Comment: Yeah, jMonkeyEngine supports post-process effects, but I'm not too familiar with them at this moment. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Mmmh, nevermind, there are simpler ways. I'll try to answer properly.

Comment: Can you use glLogicOp(GL_XOR)? http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glLogicOp.xml

Comment: Note that inversion doesn't guarantee you visibility in a whole bunch of corner cases, like unsaturated grays, and provides poor visibility for many other cases.

Comment: @LarsViklund Interesting. How could one solve these corner cases? And is there a better blend function then the one for inversion?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The quick and easy way to do this is to use the standard blending equation with the following parameters:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO);
```

If `src` is the source colour (the one from your new object) and `dst` is the destination colour (the one which is in the framebuffer) it will compute the new colour as follows:

```
new = src * (1 - dst) + dst * 0
    = src * (1 - dst)
```

So you just need to set `src = 1`, *ie.* white, and you will get inverse video. The GLSL fragment shader will be:

```
void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you know your alpha blending!