# What are the rest of the blending functions used for?

Tags: xna, opengl, graphics, directx, blending

In general, I know of five ways to make use of blending functions (these are for OpenGL, but replace `glBlendFunc()` with `SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND)` and `SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND)` for DirectX):

`glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`: Alpha blending (not premultiplied)

`glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`: Alpha blending (premultiplied)

`glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE)`: Additive blending

`glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_SRC_COLOR)`: Multiplicative blending

`glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_SRC_COLOR)`: 2x Multiplicative blending (somewhat obscure)

But there are so many other values you can use when setting your blending function, and not only I've never seen them in use, but also have no idea what they could be used for. In particular, I don't see what `GL_DST_ALPHA` could be used for.

What the rest of the blending functions used for?

Comment: I have nothing to add to Nicol Bolas’s answer, but see [this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/28649/5864) for yet another example.

Comment: Do you mind editing your question to be more generic and adding the `xna` tag? XNA's has similar blending options too.

Comment: @Sam inverting is a nice trick.

Answer (score 5):

You have to stop thinking of blend equations (and *any* graphics mechanism or tool) as "what it looks like." Blend equations are not "additive", "multiplicative" or anything of the sort. The blend equations *do math*; that's all they do.

The question is how you *use* that math to achieve a desired visual effect. The limits are your imagination. If you can't see how these could be used, then it's a problem with your vision, not the tool.

Destination alpha, for example, can be used for various effects. Certain objects in a scene can lay down alpha, and later, you can use this alpha in a blend equation as a key to whether you show some overlaying effect. Thus, this overlay is visible only on certain objects, and only to various degrees based on that alpha.

Comment: "additive" and "multiplicative" are just names that describe a mathematical process. If I draw something, and on top I draw something else with `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE)`, I'm doing something called "Additive blending", you can call it whatever you want, or don't call it anything if you're so inclined. I know I can do whatever I want with my blending functions and my shaders, and just want to know if there are other named techniques that can be done by just changing the blending function. I'm really sorry you took the question so personally.

Comment: @PandaPajama: I didn't take anything "personally"; I'm pointing out that you need to stop relying on crutches like "named techniques" and look at the tool *as a tool*, not as a set of canned techniques.

Comment: -1 this is a good beginner's question and the answer is basically "get lost, it's math." That's obvious, but what's the use of these modes?

Comment: Canned techniques are not bad per-se. I'm sure one can implement the vast majority of visual effects with just the most common canned techniques. I know of five, and I would like to know if there are more.

Comment: @ashes999: "*the answer is basically "get lost, it's math."*" No, the answer is, "it's math; stop thinking in terms of canned techniques." That's a far more valuable lesson than memorizing and regurgitating someone else's thoughts and ideas. The use of these modes is *whatever you can find a use for them*. That's how a graphics programmer thinks.

Comment: By that logic, instead of arithmetics, children should be taught number theory and group theory, and stop them from regurgitating someone else's thoughts and canned ideas such as natural numbers, addition and multiplication, since those are all things you can build with the Peano axioms.

Comment: That's not it at all. You're trying to map a really large set of functions onto a really small set of named functions that are commonly used for image manipulation. You should be thinking about it as a function of two variables, just as we're taught about addition as a function of two variables instead of something to memorize. We're taught how to add and can then do addition on all numbers. Instead of giving a set of values a name, try thinking about it as `color = src * A + dst * B`, so that you aren't stumped with a new set of values, just as you aren't stumped when you see `393448 + 98943`

Comment: @PandaPajama: "*children should be taught number theory and group theory*" I hope you realize that, in your analogy,... you're the child. I simply don't believe in talking down to beginners. And I *really* don't believe in helping beginners to hobble themselves by showing them a few common blend equations so that they don't have to think about how blending actually works. You do more good by forcing beginners to think about the reality of the feature. They may be beginners, but assuming that they can't reason for themselves is not a teaching path I endorse.

Comment: @PandaPajama: By making them think about how to use the feature directly, rather than copying-and-pasting canned responses, you not only know that they understand it, you give them the tools to use it in novel and unique ways.

Comment: @RobertRouhani Nobody's trying to map a whole set of functions into a few named techniques. My question is all about other _common_ techniques that can be achieved by changing the blending functions. I know what's going on behind, and I know I can do very specific stuff by changing the render states and my shaders as I wish. But I'm asking about other _common_ techniques _that have names_, for example `GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO` will invert the color, and it's pretty obvious why.

Comment: @NicolBolas Of course I am the child in my analogy. If I weren't, I wouldn't have made such an analogy. I'm still learning new stuff every day, but you clearly already know everything there is to know about everything. My point is that learning common solutions does not mean you have to forfeit learning the reasoning behind them, and how to modify them and roll out your new ones whenever you need to. I wonder what kind of pupils you had, who will eternally close their minds once you teach them a single common technique to solve a problem.